# Creating a new EBS Volume from Snapshot using Ansible doesn't return Volume ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

When I try to specify the Snapshot Id using `ec2_vol` module, the snapshots gets created but it doesn't return the volume id. I saw couple of articles in GitHub discussion about known bug but the use cases are little different. Is there any work around for that ?

```
  - name: Volume Creation
    ec2_vol:
      snapshot: "snap-1234"
      zone: us-east-1a
      region: us-east-1
      volume_size: 50
      volume_type: gp2
    register: newebsvolume

  - debug: var= newebsvolume
```

Result

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "newebsvolume": {
            "changed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "",
                "module_complex_args": {
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "snapshot": "snap-12345",
                    "state": "present",
                    "volume_size": 50,
                    "volume_type": "gp2",
                    "zone": "us-east-1a"
                },
                "module_name": "ec2_vol"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [latest version of the ec2_vol](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/amazon/ec2_vol.py) module addresses this issue, so you might want to upgrade the version of Ansible you're using if you're not already running a very recent version.  I took a quick look through the history of the file in github and it looks like the module has been returning a `volume_id` value as of at least version 1.8.

Edit: Actually, after closer look it appears that the module is working properly.  All of the examples in the documentation for ec2_vol show that either `instance` or `id` is set when creating a new volume.  If you don't specify one of those then the module effectively does nothing, which is why your results are returning `"changed": false`. From the documentation it doesn't look like the module supports the creation of volumes without attaching them to an instance.

Comment: thats strange ansible version in my mac is 1.9.4

Comment: Makes sense - but the playbook results in creation of a new volume. I see that happening - is there a hack to fetch that result. Not in the same pass - but running another module with list to fetch that ?

Comment: The behavior you're describing sounds like a [reported bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1308) that's identified as [fixed as of October 19](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/2180).  As the [release history](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases) shows no releases other than 2.x release candidates a simple update won't suffice.  You might try downloading the latest version of ec2_vol.py manually and using that.  I'd recommend doing that over trying to work around a documented bug.